# Pass array of object to curl

Tags: javascript, arrays, shell, curl, request

I've this array of objects in a request:

```
.... -a [{version:07/02,test:true}] .....
```

This request goes into a JS module. This modules calls a shell script which makes the curl request:

```
await shellExec(`bash ${__dirname}/test.sh  ${program.array}`);
```

In the SH script I'm receiving this value with:

```
ARRAY=$1

curl -I "https://localhost:3031/execution/?array=$ARRAY
```

Now I'm getting the following error message:

> curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification

When I change the value now to a string for example, everything works fine but I need to pass an array of objects. Theres no way around.

So is there someone who has an idea how I can fix this in a short and good way?

Comment: `[{version:07/02,test:true}]` needs to be quoted.

Comment: @Barmar I did "[{version:07/02,test:true}]" but the error is still visible

Comment: What is the type of `program.array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The needs to be quoted so that the shell won't try to parse the special characters in it.

```
... -a '[{version:07/02,test:true}]' ...
```

Since you're passing this to `ShellExec`, it needs to be quoted just like you would if you were entering it as arguments in an interactive shell.

Make sure the caller sanitizes this string. If they send

```
... -a '[{version:07/02,test:true}]' ...; rm -fr *
```

it would be quite a disaster.

Comment: I've copied this but I'm getting an undefined error when trying to execute the script

Comment: What does it say is undefined?

Comment: What is the type of `program.array`. I assumed it was an array because of the name.

Comment: It looks exactly like defined in the request: [{version:07/02,test:true}] I'm receiving it via commander: program.option("-a --array<items>", "test array")

Comment: Then the caller needs to quote it properly. `program.option("-a '[{version:07/02,test:true}]'", "test array")`

Comment: Just like they would if they were entering it by hand in the shell.

Comment: I've also tried to escape it there with double qoutes but the error occured again. Should I try single ones instead? And thanks for trying to help me! I really appreciate this

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the correct quoting.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll check it tomorrow @work and let you know if it works :)

Comment: I needed to escape it like \{\{ .... So this works now for me without any quotes. Maybe you can update your answer? And thanks for bringing me on the right way :)

Comment: Quoting and escaping are two different ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: I'd need to see the full code to make a stab at explaining what's wrong.

Comment: I've used it in a normal curl like you wrote but it don't worked until I used backslashes.

Comment: I need to see some actual code, not a description of it.